# Kubernetes: where are the types that define securityContext defaults?

Tags: kubernetes, terminology

The Kubernetes API docs [state](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workloads-resources/pod-v1/#security-context):

> SecurityContext holds pod-level security attributes and common container settings. Optional: Defaults to empty. **See type description for default values** of each field.

What "types" are they referring to, and where exactly are these default values documented?

Comment: Is [this](https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#securitycontext-v1-core) what you're looking for?

Comment: So does "type" just mean PodSecurityContext vs [Container] SecurityContext? (That is, treating the config section as a nonprimitive **datatype**.)  And not distinguishing between the **resource types/kinds** where those fields are utilised (such as Deployment vs StatefulSet)?

Comment: In the linked docs you can see that "Some fields are present in both `SecurityContext` and `PodSecurityContext`. When both are set, the values in `SecurityContext` take precedence." In order to check description of each field you should refer to table and check TYPE description. Defaults can also be found there.

Comment: Are SecurityContext and PodSecurityContext resource-types (or kinds) in the  [standard API terminology](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#standard-api-terminology)?

Comment: `securityContext` field in the pod manifest is a `PodSecurityContext` **object** that saves security context in the Kubernetes API. And [Kinds](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#types-kinds) are grouped into three categories: Objects, Lists, Simple. The term "kind" is reserved for these "top-level" API types. The term "type" should be used for distinguishing sub-categories within objects or subobjects.

Comment: @Wytrz are you saying securityContext (and PodSec..) _are_ "kinds" (of the first category) or _are not_ (and if not then why, e.g. what defines top-level, and what are subobjects etc)?

Comment: I have dug deeper into go-client specification in order to resolve your confusion with that terminology. `securitycontext` [is considered as a type](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/securitycontext#pkg-types). Each type contains subobjects with values, for example: `type ContainerSecurityContextAccessor`,
`type ContainerSecurityContextMutator`, etc which are described [here](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/api/core/v1#PodSecurityContext).

Comment: And "top-level" API types are for example: `Pod`, `ReplicationController`, `Service`. You can see that [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#pod-v1-core) `Pod` has the `kind` field.

Comment: @benjimin Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find the the official API documentation regarding the `SecurityContext` for the 4 latest Kubernetes versions:

- [1.17](https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#securitycontext-v1-core)
- [1.18](https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#securitycontext-v1-core)
- [1.19](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#securitycontext-v1-core)
- [1.20](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#securitycontext-v1-core)

Additionally, you can find more explanations regarding the [API Conventions](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#api-conventions) in the linked docs. And as I already mentioned in the comments the main difference between `kind` and `type` is:

> The term "kind" is reserved for these "top-level" API types. The term
> "type" should be used for distinguishing sub-categories within objects
> or subobjects.